# Ruby link to anchor on other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, hyperlink

I created an anchor `<a name="anchor"></a>` on a different page than the link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/image.png'),  newpage_path,:anchor => "anchor" %>
```

This links to the newpage_path, but starts all the way on top, it's not linking to the anchor.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) still use a named route for this. Try this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/image.png'), newpage_path(:anchor => "anchor") %>
```

Search this page for the text `anchor` for documentation on this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/image.png'), {:controller => "newpage", :anchor => "anchor"}, :class => "yourstyle" %>
```

Comment: How should I define the route, because it's looking for index, I get the following error: No route matches {:controller=>"newpage", :action=>"index"}

Comment: my standard routes for anchors work fine, e.g. `resources newpage`, or limited, `resources newpage, :only => [:index]`

Comment: I'm using this for about_path: get 'newpage' => 'pages#newpage', but looks like I have to make a method in a controller, right?

Comment: Yes, all actions map back to a controller method.  In the case of the route you have mapped the link instead would be `<%= link_to image_tag('/assets/image.png'), {:controller => "pages", :action => 'newpage', :anchor => "anchor"}, :class => "yourstyle" %>`